# Google Now opens when not needed

Tags: huawei, google-voice-actions

From time to time Google (voice) search randomly starts on my phone (Huawei Ascend Y300, Android version 4.1.1)

I'll be listening to music for example, change songs, and out of nowhere Google voice search will open, I have completely no idea what button I'm pressing or what I'm doing to activate this, but knowing what opens this will be of great help.

I've gone to the settings, Google Now is already turned off and there doesn't seem to be anything relevant there I can do.

How do I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: When you change your music, do you use buttons on your earbuds? Also, I don't really understand what your second question is. Could you explain more?